# How to access global variables in Meteor template without using a helper?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I have all my image files served from a different domain, and I put that host name as a variable into Meteor.settings. Then, how can I access this variable within a Meteor template?

For example, in this template, what's the best practice to replace `img.example.com` with a variable defined in Meteor.settings or some other global variables? I don't think it's a good idea to pass it to every template by using helpers.

```html
<template name="products">
  {{#each items}}
    <img src="http://img.example.com/{{id}}.png">
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way how you can pass data into your templates is via helpers. You can use [global helper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper):

```
Template.registerHelper('imgExampleUrl', function() {
   return 'img.example.com';
});
```

Then you can use global helper in many templates:

```
<template name="products">
  {{#each items}}
    <img src="http://{{imgExampleUrl}}/{{id}}.png">
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="otherTemplate">
    <img src="http://{{imgExampleUrl}}/{{id}}.png">
</template>
```

Or if you want to get value of imgExampleUrl from settings.json

```
Template.registerHelper('imgExampleUrl', function() {
   return Meteor.settings.public.imgExampleUrl;
});
```

Your settings.json:

```
{
  "public": {
    "imgExampleUrl": "img.example.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: And without a helper like the question asks, how do you do it ? ... for example I don't want to polute my global helpers with variables

Comment: The only way how you can pass data into your templates is via helpers.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Js file do like this. It may help you

```
Template.yourTemplateName.varNameYouhavetoaccess= function(){
    return getYourGlobalValueHere;
  }
```

And In HTML page in your template you can iterate value `{{varNameYouhavetoaccess}}`

Or You can use Helper

In JS file:

Template.nametag.helpers({
  name: "Ben Bitdiddle"
  });

In HTML:

```
<template name="nametag">
  <p>My name is {{name}}.</p>
</template>
```

Comment: But, doesn't that mean I have to define a wrapper or helper for **every** template that will be using this variable? That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a global function with return type

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
 getItems = function(){
//do your stuffs
 return items;
}
```

Your template

```
<template name="products">
    {{#each items}}
    <img src="http://{{imgExampleUrl}}/{{id}}.png">
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Helpers

```
Template.products.helpers({
  items : function(){
    return getItems();
  }
});
```

You can use `getItems()` from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what op was asking for but this page came up on Google when searching for "How to access Meteor settings from template".

I expanded on @Tomas Hromnik's soultion and made this global template helper:

**helpers.js**

```
Template.registerHelper('meteorSettings', function(settings) {
  var setting = Meteor.settings.public;
  if (settings) {
    var eachSetting = settings.split('.');
    for (i = 0; i < eachSetting.length; i++) {
      setting = setting[eachSetting[i]];
    }
  }
  return setting;
});
```

**home.html**

```
<template name="home">
  <!--
    Basically the same as doing this: (except you can't do this)
    {{#if Meteor.settings.public.instagram.access_token}}
  -->
  {{#if (meteorSettings 'instagram.access_token')}}
    <div class="instagram"></div>
  {{/if}}

  <!--
    You can also set Meteor.settings.public to a variable to access multiple settings
  -->
  {{#let settings=meteorSettings}}
    {{settings.instagram.access_token}}
  {{/let}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Template.registerHelper('var', name => {
  const data = Template.instance().data || {};
  return data[name];
});
```

Inside template:

```
{{var 'someVariableFromTemplate'}}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.