# Meteor: Is there any way to use the JS global variable in the Template?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

i wanted to access global js variable in the meteor blaze template. i have a set of data coming from an api, i have a json data stored in a global variable, when i display the data in the template i have to do some data manipulation by mapping the json object with api data, is there any way to do this in the template ?

```
<template name="myTemp">
   {{Data coming from api}} //not able to global variable here to compare and do data manipulation
</template>
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839755/how-to-access-global-variables-in-meteor-template-without-using-a-helper

Answer (score 4):

well you cannot directly access a global variable in `blaze`. A tricky solution would be to make a template `helper` and access that global variable. it'd be something like this.

```
globalVar = 'hello';
Template.myTemp.helpers({
    'gv': function(){return globalVar;}
});
```

then you'd be able to access in blaze like this

```
{{ gv }}
```